# R Shiny: fileInput, NULL appearing at end of str() console output

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest

Using R shiny, I am developing a simple app that allows user to input data from a file and do some simple analysis. My first step is allow the input-ing and have a reactive wrapper based on the input options given the user. The following will explain what I am doing:

server.R:

```
require(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input,output){
    Data<-reactive({
        datFile<-input$datFile
        path<-as.character(datFile$datapath)
        df<-read.csv(path,
                     header=input$datHeader,
                     sep=input$datSep,
                     quote=input$datQuote,
                     stringsAsFactors=F)

        print(str(df)) # <---- print to console
        return(df)
   })

output$dataPreview<-renderTable({
    if (is.null(Data())) return(NULL)
    data.frame(Data()[1:input$previewRows,])
},digits=3)
})
```

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  titlePanel("My app"),

  #sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(

    tags$hr(),

    #data input
    fileInput('datFile',
              tags$h5(tags$strong('Choose .csv or .txt file to upload local file')),
              accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),

    tags$hr(),

    #checkbox to indicate header == true or false
    checkboxInput('datHeader','Header contains attribute names', TRUE),

    tags$hr(),

    #file type
    radioButtons('datSep',
                 tags$h5(tags$strong("Separator")),
                 c("Comma(.csv)"=',',
                   "Tab(.txt/.tsv)"='\t'),
                 ','),

    tags$hr(),

    #quotation used in data file
    radioButtons('datQuote',
                 tags$h5(tags$strong('Quotes used in data file')),
                 c(None='',
                   'Double Quotes'='"',
                   'Single Quotes'="'"),
                 '"'),

    tags$hr(),

    #transpose data
    checkboxInput('datTranspose','Transpose data?',FALSE),
    width=3), #end sidebar panel

  mainPanel(
    tags$h4("Displaying a preview of your data"),
    sliderInput("previewRows","Number of rows to display",
                min=1,max=20,value=10,step=1,animate=TRUE),
    tableOutput("dataPreview"))
))
```

Problem is that when the

```
print(str(df)) # <---- print to console
```

line runs, a NULL appears at the end of my console output:

```
'data.frame':   32561 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ age           : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
 $ workclass     : Factor w/ 9 levels " ?"," Federal-gov",..: 8 7 5 5 5 5 5 7 5 5 ...
 $ fnlwgt        : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
 $ education     : Factor w/ 16 levels " 10th"," 11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
 $ education.num : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
 $ marital.status: Factor w/ 7 levels " Divorced"," Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 ...
 $ occupation    : Factor w/ 15 levels " ?"," Adm-clerical",..: 2 5 7 7 11 5 9 5 11 5 ...
 $ relationship  : Factor w/ 6 levels " Husband"," Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ race          : Factor w/ 5 levels " Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
 $ sex           : Factor w/ 2 levels " Female"," Male": 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ capital.gain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ capital.loss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hours.per.week: int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ native.country: Factor w/ 42 levels " ?"," Cambodia",..: 40 40 40 40 6 40 24 40 40 40 ...
 $ income        : Factor w/ 2 levels " <=50K"," >50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
NULL
```

Dataset is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

Here is a link to the exact file that I used:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36842028/linkouts/adult.txt

This NULL is apparently affecting my downstream analysis, in particular randomForest(). I had to track this NULL all the way from my machine learning step to the data input step. Any idea why this little guy is here?? Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `NULL` this appears to be a result of `print.default` acting on the result 
of `str` which has class `NULL`.

```
> print(str(data.frame(a=1:2, b= 3:4)))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2
 $ b: int  3 4
NULL
> str(data.frame(a=1:2, b= 3:4))
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2
 $ b: int  3 4
```

you can remove the `print` so change to

```
str(df) # <---- print to console
return(df)
```

in `server.R` and you will observe:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7847
'data.frame':   32561 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ age           : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
 $ workclass     : chr  " State-gov" " Self-emp-not-inc" " Private" " Private" ...
 $ fnlwgt        : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
 $ education     : chr  " Bachelors" " Bachelors" " HS-grad" " 11th" ...
 $ education.num : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
 $ marital.status: chr  " Never-married" " Married-civ-spouse" " Divorced" " Married-civ-spouse" ...
 $ occupation    : chr  " Adm-clerical" " Exec-managerial" " Handlers-cleaners" " Handlers-cleaners" ...
 $ relationship  : chr  " Not-in-family" " Husband" " Not-in-family" " Husband" ...
 $ race          : chr  " White" " White" " White" " Black" ...
 $ sex           : chr  " Male" " Male" " Male" " Male" ...
 $ capital.gain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
 $ capital.loss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hours.per.week: int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
 $ native.country: chr  " United-States" " United-States" " United-States" " United-States" ...
 $ income        : chr  " <=50K" " <=50K" " <=50K" " <=50K" ...
```

in the console.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! looks like i have another bug somewhere to dig out